# Skype Screen Sharing Without Webcam

Tags: skype, webcam

Is this possible?  I know Skype has screen sharing for video calling, but I cannot start a video call without a webcam.   Just curious if there was a way to share a screen without a webcam.

Edit:  I seem to be missing the "Share" menu icon, anyone else have this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way, I have done it many times myself.  Open an IM (instant messaging) conversation with the person, then click screen share, and it will start an audio call, but no video...you can always mute the microphone on your end...

The Skype instant message window:
[image]

Comment: The share menu seems to be gone in the latest version

Comment: But turns out you can share screen from a voice call